# (UK) Connect the mains ground to equipment negative on the secondary side

Tags: grounding

I am planning to connect a Recom RAC04-12SC/W to an Adafruit Feather board that's powered by a 12 V to 5 V DC/DC converter. The Arduino board is using an SSR-40 DA solid-state relay (SSR) to switch mains power.

Would it be feasible / permitted / allowed / best practice to connect the negative/ground on the electronics to the ground wire from the mains?

The Recom device has the Class II appliance marking and the case is a standard BS wall-mounted mains socket enclosure.

Comment: If you can keep stuff isolated, it's probably better. If you have a compelling reason to connect then state what it is please.

Comment: No compelling reason, the question is based on ignorance. My experience is low voltage DC <30v, ~ 100A. This is an unusual embedded project which has me scrathing my head.

Comment: It would make the output Class 1 which may or may not be a problem in your product. Is it possible an end user would connect it to a non-earthed outlet? If yes, any Y-capacitor leakage from the primary side will be present on the output. If touchable, it's unpleasant. Do you use the output side to connect to anything outside of the product, any interface or similar?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site :-) What other interfaces does you board have, does it have communication cables going to other equipment? At the very least, it'll have a programming cable going to a PC laptop. By understanding that, we can understand if there's any ground loops that may be created by grounding your electronics's 0 V. Thanks.